# Some issues regarding implementation of Pull to Refresh using SwipeRefreshLayout

Tags: android, android-fragments, swiperefreshlayout

I am using pull to refresh in my fragment to refresh the data fetched through a json url .
But the problem which i am facing is that,as soon as i land on a fragment page the swipe refresh widget starts and the data starts loading but if in case before fetching the data from the internet i slide my viewpager to a new fragment page and then immediately come to the previous page where the data was loading,then a new Swipe Refresh widget come over the previously existing widget,Hence there are two overlapping widgets and one widget always remains on the screen even if the data is loaded .I have used **setRefrshing(false)** but it is not working according to my requirements.

**Fragment.java**

```
    public class Africa extends Fragment implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener{

    //ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    //private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    private CountryDataAdapter adapter;
    private ArrayList<CountriesData> data;
    private SwipeRefreshLayout swipe;
    EasyTracker easyTracker;

    public Africa(){

    }
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        easyTracker = EasyTracker.getInstance(getActivity());
        // setContentView(R.layout.countrydata);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        //pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this.getContext(), ProgressDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.countrydata, container, false);

        //mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view1);
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)v.findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view1);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        adapter=new CountryDataAdapter(getActivity());
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        // loadJSON();

        swipe=(SwipeRefreshLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.swipe_refresh_layout);
        swipe.setOnRefreshListener(this);
        swipe.setColorSchemeColors(R.color.b, R.color.p, R.color.g, R.color.o);
        //  loadRetro();
        final boolean ref=swipe.isRefreshing();
        if(ref) loadRetro();
        else
        {
            swipe.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                        swipe.setRefreshing(true);
                        loadRetro();
                    easyTracker.send(MapBuilder.createEvent("Home Page", "Swipe", "Africa", null).build());
                }
            }, 500);
        }

        return v;
    }

    private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager
                = (ConnectivityManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(
            Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_refresh) {
            boolean x=isNetworkAvailable();
            if(x)
            {

                swipe.setRefreshing(true);
                loadRetro();
                easyTracker.send(MapBuilder.createEvent("Home Page", "Refresh", "Africa", null).build());
                return true;
            }
            else Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No Internet Connection!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRefresh(){
//        swipe.setRefreshing(true);
//        loadRetro();
        if(!swipe.isRefreshing()) {
            swipe.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    swipe.setRefreshing(true);
                    loadRetro();
                }
            }, 1500);
        }
        else loadRetro();
        easyTracker.send(MapBuilder.createEvent("Home Page", "Pull To Refresh", "Africa", null).build());
//        pDialog.dismiss();

    }


    public void loadRetro(){

        // swipe.setRefreshing(true);
//        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
//        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
//        pDialog.show();
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://www.appuonline.com")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        jsonrequest request = retrofit.create(jsonrequest.class);
        Call<JsonResponse> call = request.getJSON5();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<JsonResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<JsonResponse> call, Response<JsonResponse> response) {
                try{
                    JsonResponse jsonResponse = response.body();
                    data = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(jsonResponse.getData()));
                    adapter.addItems(data);
                    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
//                    if (pDialog.isShowing())
//                        pDialog.dismiss();
                    swipe.setRefreshing(false);}
                catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<JsonResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                try{
                    Log.d("Error", "no connection");
                    swipe.setRefreshing(false);}
                catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

set Offset limit to your ViewPager.

example:

```
pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(5); //5 is count of pages in viewpager
```

Comment: this will not recycle previous fragment.

Comment: which means your old fragment will remain as it is. (not reload again)

Comment: I have set my viewpager in the mainActivity.java,so should i set this command over there ??

Comment: Yes it worked ,but i want refresh my page after sometime automatically by showing that refresh widget ,so how will that work ???

Comment: i have used it .Just look at the `loadRetro()` method .As soon as the data will be loaded , i have set `swipe.setRefreshing(false);`

Comment: if you manually swipe the layout, then u get 2 refreshing views??

Comment: No.I dont get two refreshing views,i only get one refreshing view.The command which you told is working correctly ,but i want that after sometime my data gets updated and again that refresh widget is shown indicating that the data is getting updated .

Comment: use AlarmManager or background Service which will refresh every 5 seconds.

Comment: How to use these terms ??

Comment: you will see check mark button on my First answer. just click on that.

Comment: Your answer was definitely helpful for me ,but please help me with the alarm manager or background service to refresh my data evry 5 sec

Answer (score 1):

for your second question:

create an Android Service class. and use `CountDownTimer` class this that service. in Service's onStartCommand() method just initialize CountDownTimer.

```
@Override
    public int onStartCommand(final Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        mCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(5000, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUnitFinished) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                //you will get status every 5 second here.
            }
        };
        mCountDownTimer.start();

        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }
```

Comment: but new Thread will work until you are using your app. this will not work in background mode.

Comment: So thats what i wanted ,i wanted to update my data when i was using my app .and again when i restart my app then the data will automatically be refreshed and updated.